# how to create edit button inside table just create

Tags: html, ajax, xml, button, datatable

I want to create edit button inside table, which can "add","delete","edit", but all the demo I seen is adding inside fixed datatable in html

but for this one, every time the table just create, how can we do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <table id="example" class="display"></table>

    <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
    //need to login in order to get authorized token
      $(document).ready(function () {
        const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

        console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

        $("#example").DataTable({
          ajax: {
            url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/all_item", 
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken 
            },
            dataSrc: function (response) {
              console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
              return response.ipcs
            }
          },          
          // Column definitions
          columns: [
            { data: "", title: "ACTION" },
            { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
            { data: "name", title: "name" },
            { data: "group", title: "group" },
            { data: "ip", title: "ip" },
            { data: "port", title: "port" },
            { data: "ipc_enable", title: "ipc_enable" },
            { data: "ftp_enable", title: "ftp_enable" },
            { data: "id", title: "id" },
            { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" },
            { data: "updated_at", title: "updated_at" }
          ]
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried add empty block called "action", that we can put edit button inside it, to edit that row

[(pic) table I creadte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGQsy.png)

---

the button is showing up, the function not work yet

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
          const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

          console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

          $("#example").DataTable({
            ajax: {
              url: "url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/all_item"",
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
              },
              dataSrc: function (response) {
                console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
                return response.ipcs
              }
            },
            // Column definitions
            columns: [
              {
                data: null,
                title: "ACTION",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                  return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit-btn" data-id="' + row.id + '">Edit</button>' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" data-id="' + row.id + '">Delete</button>';
                }
              },
              { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
              { data: "name", title: "name" },
              { data: "group", title: "group" },
              { data: "ip", title: "ip" },
              { data: "port", title: "port" },
              { data: "ipc_enable", title: "ipc_enable" },
              { data: "ftp_enable", title: "ftp_enable" },
              { data: "id", title: "id" },
              { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" },
              { data: "updated_at", title: "updated_at" }
            ]
          });

          // Edit row function
          $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            editRow(id);
          });

          // Delete row function
          $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            deleteRow(id);
          });

          function editRow(id) {
            // TODO: editRow logic
            console.log("Edit row with id:", id);
          }

          function deleteRow(id) {
            // TODO: deleteRow logic
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        });

    </script>
```